# Create PDF using HTML2PDF with TCPDF and including new pages based in a pre-existing PDF File

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, html2pdf

How can I create a new pages in a run-time HTML2PDF conversion using other PDFs as new pages?

I have a routine to convert some HTML data to PDF, but inside it may I need to merge a uploaded PDF file, sometimes it is a image or a doc file, easy to convert in html or media to put on PDF, but how can I merge a pre-existing PDF File as a new page at this existing PDF?

Answer (score 1):

Our software @cloudformatter can prepend or append existing PDFs to a formatted div or set of div's.

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.CustomTipsTricks.InjectPDF

That is a sample page showing both pre-pending and appending an existing PDF to a dynamically formatted div with instructions on how to do it.

Usage instructions for the jQuery plugin are here http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage

Comment: Very interesting component, but I'm talking about a PHP component , even thought to generate it on the frontend but I need to generate it on the backend because customers use machines with little processing power and I'm talking about generating PDFs with  more than 50 pages .

Comment: That is why the PDF in our component is not client side. The browser is the display. The HTML DOM is scraped with all CSS resolved, cleaned up a bit locally in Javascript to make XML and then sent to a remote formatter. You could use node server side to accomplish the same, sending the formatting to our @cloudformatter server for sure. There are users that are formatting documents that are 200+ pages.

Comment: I will take a look at the solution. 
I have more 10 different file types(DWG, DOCs, etc) to be converted to PDF or image. Data entry takes place dynamically, so I do not have accurate knowledge of how many merges i'll have to do.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The question was about HTML2PDF and not other external libraries